# Error Sending multipart form data (file upload) through WSO2 API Manager

Tags: rest, file-upload, multipartform-data, wso2

I am using WSO2's API Manager to provide access to my REST APIs. For the most part, this has worked as expected. However, when attempting to upload a file, it seems that the data is somehow being transformed or truncated by the API manager.

When the server (WebAPI) attempts to read the incoming file, it throws an exception:

```
"Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete."
```

I ran a packet capture to see exactly what was happening to the data. It is definitely being modified; when the client sends this for the multipart boundary:

```
ContentType:  multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycERX4y7BIbMWyr9j
```

The server receives this:

```
ContentType:  multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=MIMEBoundary_d3d321395e018c038f76372bacdee393c805f83beb71e614
```

So far, not a problem. But when I look at the payload in the first frame, I am sending 1323 bytes and receiving 1317 bytes. The data is identical until the last six bytes, which are simply missing.

After the file, the client sends another part:

```
HTTPPayloadLine: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"
HTTPPayloadLine: 123
HTTPPayloadLine: ------WebKitFormBoundarycERX4y7BIbMWyr9j--
```

However the server does not receive this at all.

What is happening to the form data when it goes through WSO2 API Manager?

Comment: Can you try with the "disable-chunking" property in the API configuration? Edit the api configuration,which is  in the synapse-conifg folder?

Comment: Ratha - thank you for your input. However, I cannot find where to add the config item you mentioned. In the API config I have <api><resource><inSequence>, etc. Is there documentation on this I could reference?

Comment: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Adding+a+Mediation+Extension, try add like this, in the insequence, <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" /> http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Properties+Reference